# Eroror compiling builtin asm

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I recently switched from [Keil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keil_(company)) [µVision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keil_(company)) to my own Makefile. I have an issue compiling a file *port.c*,

The function in the file:

```
__asm void vPortSVCHandler( void )
{
    PRESERVE8

    /* Get the location of the current TCB. */
    ldr r3, =pxCurrentTCB
    ldr r1, [r3]
    ldr r0, [r1]
    /* Pop the core registers. */
    ldmia r0!, {r4-r11, r14}
    msr psp, r0
    isb
    mov r0, #0
    msr basepri, r0
    bx r14
}
```

When compiling I get these errors:

```
../port.c:52:7: error: expected '(' before 'void'
   52 | __asm void vPortSVCHandler( void )
      |       ^~~~
      |       (
../port.c:64:13: error: stray '#' in program
   64 |     mov r0, #0
```

Am I missing an include or a compiler option?

Comment: Inline assembler isn't standardized (like in C++) nor is it portable. Every single compiler does it in it's own way. Good compilers strive to do it in "C++ style" which is `asm(" ... ");`, while waiting for the C committee to recognize that people might want to use C on computers. It's been over 30 years since the first C standard and the committee has still not realized the need to use C on computers, so don't get your hopes up...

Comment: Would it work to just change "port.c" to "port.cpp" ?

Comment: No because this looks nothing like the standardized C++ inline assembler. And you generally don't want to use C++ in embedded systems anyway.

Comment: @Lundin `And you generally don't want to use C++ in embedded systems anyway` why? I use sometimes. No problems. Nice RTOS available as well (distortos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `gcc` and gcc does not have "asm" functions.

You need to write it in the assembler or write the inline assembly. `__asm` is also not valid `gcc` keyword.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Comment: Is it possible to compile it without modifying the source file ?

Comment: Use keil comand line compiler instaed of gcc

Comment: Can not use it in MSVC?

Comment: @NicholasJela MSVC uses yet another syntax on x86, and doesn't support inline assembly at all on x64. In my experience it's better to write your assembly in separate assembly files, and then use a dedicated assembler rather than relying on the C compiler assembler.